# How to use ReactJS on Rails without react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, haml

i want to try `react` on rails.

but i dont know how to use it correctly.

i put the `require` at the head of `application.coffee`, and copy some code form facebook's

```
#= require react/react
#= require react/JSXTransformer
#= require react/react-with-addons.min

$ ->
  Hello = React.createClass
    render: ->
      `<h1>H</h1>`

  view = document.querySelector('#content')
  React.render(`<Hello/>`, view)
```

why i use **`** in the template is because `react-rails` use it for JSX.

but finally, i got the error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

so, who can help me? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSXTransformer` script only transforms JSX inside `<script>` tags with `type=text/jsx`. Making it work within the Rails asset pipeline is a bit more involved.

React-Rails does this by [registering a new Tilt engine for `.jsx` files](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/1c03b00b8105c78fbf674abe34be4941084bede4/lib/react/rails/engine.rb#L5) on startup which [calls `JSX::transform`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/1c03b00b8105c78fbf674abe34be4941084bede4/lib/react/jsx/template.rb#L12-14), which in turn [manually invokes the JSX transformer](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/1c03b00b8105c78fbf674abe34be4941084bede4/lib/react/jsx/transformer.rb#L21-24) as part of the asset pipeline.

Comment: thanks @BinaryMuse , is that mean that if I do not use the `react-rails`, I can not use `JSXTransformer` ?

Comment: @GeminiYellow You could probably cobble something together, but my guess is that it would end up looking very much like react-rails anyway.

Comment: thank you @BinaryMuse ,but oh,it is so awful.  that let me fell rails too bad or react too bad.